# Castle Windsor - How to register MVC controllers in web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, aop

I currently use my own Dependency Injection framework.  It is extremely lightweight and does the job, however I am looking to do Aspect Oriented Programming and need something better.  I am testing Castle Windsor because of it's capability to do proxy-based runtime interception.

I wrote a simple MVC application using Castle Windsor installing from web.config and it works fine.  The problem is that I had to register each controller individually. In an application with a lot of controllers, this will become tedious.

**web.config**

```
<castle>
  <components>
    <component id="LoggerInterceptor" type="MvcApp.LoggerInterceptor, MvcApp" lifestyle="Singleton"/>
    <component Name="AccountController" type="MvcApp.Controllers.AccountController, MvcApp" lifestyle="Transient">
      <interceptors>
        <interceptor>${LoggerInterceptor}</interceptor>
      </interceptors>
    </component>
    <component Name="HomeController" type="MvcApp.Controllers.HomeController, MvcApp" lifestyle="Transient">
      <interceptors>
        <interceptor>${LoggerInterceptor}</interceptor>
      </interceptors>
    </component>      
  </components>
</castle>
```

Using the Fluent Registration API method of registration, it is possible to register all of the controllers in a single line of code.  Unfortunately, this completely defeats the purpose of using runtime proxies.  If I want my AOP configuration to compile with my code, I will use something like PostSharp which does compile time weaving.

**Fluent Registration API**

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
{
    container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
             .BasedOn<IController>()
             .LifestyleTransient()
             .Configure((c => c.LifeStyle.Transient.Interceptors<LogInterceptor>())));
}
```

I will always be registering my controllers so having that in code is not an issue, however I will want to determine what dependencies, parameters and interceptors are used via config.

So ...

Is there a way to register all of the controllers via web.config with a single component element?

Or

Is there a way to mix the configurations such that the controllers are registered via code, but their interceptors are done in the web.config?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to register all of the controllers via web.config with
>   a single component element?

I guees not

> Is there a way to mix the configurations such that the controllers are
>   registered via code, but everything else is done in the web.config?

Sure. Let say you have one of your controller depending on a specific service.
You can register all your controllers via Fluent api as you did and register that single service explicitly in the config.
Just keep in mind what you register in the config will be registered first int the container.
Order registration is relevant only in case of multiple registration for same interface, not for resolution itself.

Comment: I am aware of this, however that does not really help.  I want to be able to modify the controller's interceptors via config such as in the example, however I was looking for a less tedious method.  Is there a way to register the controllers via the Fluent API, but add their interceptors via web.config (In a single component element)?   BTW, I modified the second question to be more specific.

Comment: Let me try to recap... you want register fluent all your controllers, but you want assign to some of them, explicitly, an interceptor from the config. If so I have no clue, but it sounds a bit awkward... If I understood correctly your need you may leverage on "Configure"(as per you your Fluent registration sample) to match a given controller and so assign a given interceptor: you may add few Configure in cascade to satisfy all your need.

Comment: I really don't want to register fluent anything.  I prefer to do that all in code so that reconfiguration does not require recompiling.

Comment: Previously in my DI, unregistered classes would be created with their default constructor instead of throwing an error.  The reaility is that even if my injector supported AOP, I would have to register every controller as well to tell it what to apply.  So in the end, I am not doing more work.  When I saw the fluent way of registering all controllers at one time, I thought that was nice.  I guess I was hoping to duplicate that in config.